# can't stop Neo4j server - ERROR: Neo4j Server not running

Tags: neo4j

My neo4j server wont stop.  Whenever my DB has my database loaded and I type:

```
./bin/neo4j stop
```

I get

```
ERROR: Neo4j Server not running
rm: remove write-protected regular file `/home/sa20/neo4j-enterprise-2.0.0/data/neo4j-service.pid'?
```

I then kill -9 the process and it corrupts my DB :(  Does anyone have any idea why this might happen.  I dont get the problem with a fresh empty DB

Comment: What do you get in `data/graph.db/messages.log` and `data/log/console.log` when trying to shut down? Which Neo4j version, which os?

Comment: it's probably running as a service and unable to find the pid with that command. uninstall as a service if you want to run neo4j start/stop.

Comment: Its not installed as a service.  All I did for unstallation was untar and started using neo4j start.  neo4j start always works.  Neo4j stop also works when the DB is clean after I wipe it but not after I fill it with data it tells me that it is not running when it clearly is.

Comment: Stefan ... When the database has my data loaded into it nothing appears in either log when i run the command neo4j stop.  when the database is clean after I wipe it the neo4j stop works and the logs show normal messages.  Its very strange

Comment: Can you check if you have `data/neo4j-service.pid` and what permissions the `data` directory has?

Comment: Redhat6.3Server x86_64

Comment: I cleared everything and re-ran.  then I have the pid file.  I must have removed it last time when the I tried to shutdown by answering 'yes' to remove it (see edited question above).  The pid permissions appear like this    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root       6 Jan 16 12:09 neo4j-service.pid

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael you led me down the right road.  It seems that my data load script was re-starting neo4j using root rather than my application user account.  This was making the owner of the .pid file  locked to my user.  Lesson learned like the old addage "don't do anything as root"